# Why do I get a NullReferenceException when using ToDictionary on an Entity Framework query?

Tags: linq-to-sql, entity-framework-6

I'm very surprised, it seems my lambda expressions are executed as C# code, instead of being converted to SQL.

If that is really the case, it's a bit sad. For example:

```
context.Set<Post>().ToDictionary(post => post.Id, post => post.Comments.Count())
```

This code will apparently load the posts into C# objects first, and then count the comments. I came to that conclusion because in a similar piece of real-world code, I was having a  `NullReferenceException` because `post.Comments` was null (note that in my code, the posts were loaded *without* the `Comments` relation just before executing this line of code).

Using this instead would then be much more efficient:

```
context.Set<Post>()
    .Select(post => new { Key = post.Id, Value = post.Comments.Count() })
    .ToDictionary(entry => entry.Key, entry => entry.Value)
```

Since I believe this code is generic enough to work in any situation, I wonder if

- Am I understanding correctly what is happening?
- Why hasn't it been implemented as a generic solution for `ToDictionary`, as it has been for `ToArray` and `ToList`?

Comment: This is more a matter of wrong expectations. There's no ToArray or ToList either. Those are IEnumerable<> extension methods. EF6 provides *async* extensions through ToListAsync,ToDictionaryAsync etc. Even those work on the results of the query, they don't modify it by appending a `Select()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `Queryable.ToDictionary` method (check [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.queryable?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2)), so `ToDictionary` takes `context.Set<Post>()` as `IEnumerable`. That means that, as you correctly understood, `context.Set<Post>()` is first evaluated and then processed in-memory.

That's highly inefficient, because now for each `Post`, comments are loaded by a separate query, if lazy loading is enabled, otherwise `Post.Comments` is `null`.

So projecting to an anonymous type is the only option to do this efficiently.

Comment: OK, silly me for thinking ToArray and ToList were implemented (overridden) by the query object ; as Panagiotis Kanavos stated in his comment, the query object only implements IEnumerable, and ToArray and ToList are just enumerating it, which in their case turns out to be what is expected, because they don't take a lambda expression as argument to extend the query (as opposed to ToDictionary, which takes two of them). Thanks for clarifying this.

Comment: Hey Gert, how do you come about to the anonymous type? Mind showing an example? Thank you!

Comment: @Nicholas Just see the question.